# Receive the keys as soon as they are pressed on Unix console

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, ros

I'm developing a C++ program on Linux to use it as a ROS node (more info about [ROS](http://www.ros.org/)).

Unix consoles buffer the entire line of text until the user press Enter, but I need to receive the keystroke as soon as the user press the key.

How can I do it?

I'm not interested in doing portable code. This is only an activity for my course at the university.

By the way, I'm running an Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS and the shell is bash.

Comment: If you don't want to manually modify terminal settings like the termios example, I would look into the curses library which may be on your system already, which provides [`getch()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of the terminal, so to turn off that feature you will need to reconfigure that terminal.  In C++ that's sth like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
```

And in any initializing function:

```
struct termios original_termios, unbuffered_termios;

tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &original_termios);
unbuffered_termios = original_termios;
unbuffered_termios.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &unbuffered_termios);
```

After that you can use any standard method to read single bytes from the file stdin (e. g. `fread()` or `getch()`).  Keep in mind that some keys send more than one byte upon being pressed (e. g. cursor keys).

When done with your stuff, you should restore the original setting, otherwise the terminal might behave weirdly even after your program has terminated:

```
tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &original_termios);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need a kind of "unbuffered" `getchar`.

You should try with [`termios`](http://shtrom.ssji.net/skb/getc.html), example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main()
{
    struct termios old_tio, new_tio;
    unsigned char c;

    /* get the terminal settings for stdin */
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO,&old_tio);

    /* we want to keep the old setting to restore them a the end */
    new_tio=old_tio;

    /* disable canonical mode (buffered i/o) and local echo */
    new_tio.c_lflag &=(~ICANON & ~ECHO);

    /* set the new settings immediately */
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSANOW,&new_tio);

    do {
         c=getchar();
         printf("%d ",c);
    } while(c!='q');

    /* restore the former settings */
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSANOW,&old_tio);

    return 0;
}
```